# Add items from HTML input to an empty array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, input

I am trying to populate a blank Javascript array with usernames inputted from a single HTML input field (input example: bill, bob, jim) but I can't get it working the way I want. The HTML code I'm using is:

```
<input id="users" type="text" placeholder="Enter Users">
<button class="btn" onclick="addTo()">Click to add names</button>
```

And the JavaScript I have so far is

```
let myarray = []

function addTo() {
  myarray.push(document.getElementById("users").value)
    }
```

The inputted data does get pushed to the array, but it gets populated as 1 single item

```
['bill, bob, jim']
```

but what I want is for it to be submitted as 3 separate items so I can access them via the index such as myarray[1]

```
['bill', 'bob', 'jim']
```

Does anyone know how I can change the code to achieve this? All of the names have to be inputted via the single HTML input field.

Comment: The addTo function is in the code block above this comment

Comment: My apologies for my apparent blindness.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
myarray.push(...document.getElementById("users").value.split(','))
```

Answer (score 0):

The missing part is: Splitting the captured string.

Embrace the function `EventTarget.addEventListener` for binding a event to an element in the DOM.

```js
const myarray = [],
      userInput = document.querySelector("#users");

document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  myarray.push(...userInput.value.split(",").map(s => s.trim()));
  
  console.log(myarray);
});
```

```html
<input id="users" type="text" placeholder="Enter Users">
<button id="btn" class="btn">Click to add names</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Observations **:**

- If user enter same name multiple times, Are we going to accept those or we are going to discard duplicates ?
- Are we storing all the names user enter on pressing `Click to add names` button ?

As per the consideration of above two points. Here is the demo **:**

```js
let myarray = []

function addTo() {
  myarray.push(...document.getElementById("users").value.split(','));
  console.log([...new Set(myarray)]);
}
```

```html
<input id="users" type="text" placeholder="Enter Users">
<button class="btn" onclick="addTo()">Click to add names</button>
```